# LazyInitializationException when field is eager

Tags: java, hibernate

I have class `OmQcActivity` like this:

```
@Entity
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
@Table(name="OM_QC_ACTIVITY")
public class OmQcActivity{
   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
   @JoinColumn(name="STATUS_ID")
   private Codesc status;
}
```

codesc is another entity.

In my code I wrote:

```
OmQcActivity  myactivity = findQCActivityById(5);
Codesc status = myactivity.getCodesc();

@Transactional(readOnly = true, propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS)
    public OmQcActivity findQCActivityById(Long id) {
        return session.load(persistentClass, id);
    }
```

however, I get:

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:86)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:140)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.invoke(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:190)
    at com.mycompany.model.OmQcActivity_$$_javassist_11.getStatus(OmQcActivity_$$_javassist_11.java)
```

how can I get Lazy exception if the fetch type is eager?

Comment: Show please Codesc code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`load()` doesn't load an entity immediately, it returns a lazy proxy that fetches the real data at the first method call. In most cases you need to use `get()` instead of `load()`.

Comment: @Odelya: In this case there are no noticeable difference in performance.

Answer (score 0):

Found this [link](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?t=73587). If you have `CollectionOfElements` annotation in your Codesc entity, then the exception about lazy initialization will be raised.